# How to organize variable which has connection with two objects

Tags: c++, class, oop

In my code, there is a class Func, which denote a function. The class FuncSet is a collection of some functions in class Func. There are two objects FuncSet set1 and FuncSet set2.

Now I would like to make up a variable which is a 2D matrix and stores the convolution of all functions in set1 and set2. I do not know which is the best way to organize this variable. If I declare it as a member in class FuncSet, this does not make sense in logic since it has some connection between two objects.

```
// class of function
class Func
{
// calculate convolution of this function and function v
double convolution(const Func & v);
}

// class of set of functions
class FuncSet
{
std::vector<Func> func;
}

// two objects set1 and set2, each of them has some Func objects. 
// For example, set1 has 10 functions and set2 has 20 functions
FuncSet set1(10);
FuncSet set2(20);

// calculate convolution of u and v, for all functions u in set1 and all functions v in set2
// it should be a 10*20 double 2D matrix
// where should I store this 2D matrix?
```

Comment: "there is a class Func, which denote a function. The class FuncSet is a collection of some functions" - Sounds to me like `std::function` and `std::vector<std::function>`. Why are you not simply doing that?

Comment: There is a member std::function in the class Func, but there are also some related subroutines in the class such as shift, index, convolution of std::function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it wherever you use it.

If you have some algorithm that is organized via a simple (cascaded) function, then you declare it just there in a function.

If you have some other class that has some tasks, some state etc., you can create a member variable there that contains these functions.

As to how to organize the "convolution" (cartesian product is clearer to me), you can either have some `vector<vector<Func>>` locally or you could put this in some additional class `FuncSetConvolution` or something like this.

What is the best solution depends on how you continue to work with it. Usually, I would strive for putting `vector<vector<Func>>` (for having functions) or `vector<vector<double>>` for the value of each combination with calculated results into some additional class. You could then write the free function:

```
FuncSetConvolution convolute(const FuncSet& set1, const FuncSet& set2);
```

which serves as creator. It seems consistent with your current style and logic.